# Issue saving TextBox data as DateTime to SQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

Basically, I am using a FormView with ItemTemplate & EditItemTemplate controls. Loading the data works fine (binding through DataSource), when I click edit (going to EditItemTemplate controls now), it works fine, but when I click save I receive the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'graduation_date', table 'dyswis.dbo.tbl_students'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails

I don't understand why it's null, when there is a value in the text box. The other form fields work fine. I suspect it has something to do with how the date is being formatted, or even the text mode.

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtGradDate" 
     Text='<%#((DateTime)Eval("graduation_date")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>' 
     CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Datasource:

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int16" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="email" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="first_name" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="last_name" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="university" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="program" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="student_number" Type="String" /><
    <asp:Parameter Name="graduation_date" Type="DateTime" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="student_card_image_name" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="id_card_image_name" Type="String" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[student_update]
    @id INT,
    @university VARCHAR(200),
    @program VARCHAR(200),
    @student_number VARCHAR(50),
    @graduation_date DATETIME,
    @student_card_image_name VARCHAR(500) = NULL,
    @id_card_image_name VARCHAR(500) = NULL
AS
    UPDATE tbl_students 
    SET university = @university, 
        program = @program, 
        student_number = @student_number, 
        graduation_date = @graduation_date 
    WHERE 
        user_id = @id
```

SQL Server table definition:

```
graduation_date DATETIME
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: I don't see any code for binding update parameters to control values. If you do it in code behind please share that code.

Comment: Unrelated tip: `graduation_date` implies you should be using the Sql type `date` rather than `datetime`.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood There is no code in the code behind. The bind happens with the FormView using a DataSource in ASPX page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to reference the filed through a `ControlParameter` like below:

If your `FormView` id is "formView" and `textBox` id is txtGradDate.

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="graduation_date" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" Type="DateTime" ControlID="formView$txtGradDate" PropertyName="Text" />
```

Comment: Got the following error: Could not find control 'formView$txtGradDate' in ControlParameter 'graduation_date'.

Comment: Got the ID in the HTML source:
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ctl01$frmStudents$txtGradDate

THIS WORKED. Is there anyway I can continue to reference the control by it's original name (txtGradDate)? I'm going to get into problems if I keep changing parent containers...

Comment: Also, why can a regular asp:parameter not work in this case? I have other textboxes that are working correctly. Is it because it's a date?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the value of `graduation_date` field from the `TextBox`.
The value can be fetched and added to the list of `UpdateParameters` using `ControlParameter`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtGradDate" 
     Text='<%#((DateTime)Eval("graduation_date")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>' 
     CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<UpdateParameters>
....
<asp:ControlParameter Name="graduation_date" ControlID="txtGradDate" Type="String" PropertyName="Text" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

Comment: The Type of String failed, but when I changed it to DateTime it worked. Also, I needed to get the full id of the control though the HTML source, txtGradDate didn't work. Any way to retain this name?